# importing own data for document classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I have folders each having  multiple text files. the folder are named on the class of the text files. How do i import these folders and files for document classification in nltk/ scikit learn. I am planning to use Bi normal separartion for feature selection and SVM for classification. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [load_files](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html) which serves this exact purpose. Here you can also find some  [examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html).

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files

dt=load_files('C:/test4',load_content=True)
print dt.target_names
X, y = dt.data, dt.target
```